# Applying transformation on a dataset spark

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a json file "currData) which contains data in {"id":integer,"url":String} format. I have loaded this file into spark datasets. Now i have written a function String clean(String) which takes an URL(String) as parameter and returns a clean version of the url(By removing the query parameters). Say the code goes something like `currDataFrame = spSession.read().json(currData);`

Now,for each url in currDataFrame, how can i apply the logic of clean function and get a new dataframe? I searched on web and there is a map function to do such transformations, but map requires an encoder? What can i provide as an encoder for Dataset type ? Thanks

Contents of currData as well as currDataFrame: `{"id":"3713","url":"https://budref.xyz.com/browse/BR-972"}`

calling clean with (https://budref.xyz.com/browse/BR-972) returns "https://budref.xyz.com/browse/"

I need an expression which when applied on currDataFrame results in 
`{"id":"3713","url":"https://budref.xyz.com/browse/"}`

Comment: you can probably just use native Spark function  `regexp_replace()`

Comment: Can you write the full expression?

Comment: now without example data and expected output

Comment: See the edited post

Comment: the regex you do in your own function can be probably just plugged into  such as `regexp_replace(column, pattern, replacement)`

Comment: Doesnt seems to work on datasets, it works on RDD's of course

Comment: you can create your own UDF, example `val clean_udf = udf((s:String) => s+"test")` and use it  with `df.select($"id", clean_udf($"url"))`

Comment: Can you please write the expression in Java?

Comment: Isnt there any way to do it using map operation on datasets ?

Comment: yes with using copy function `ds.map(d => d.copy(url=clean(d.url)))`. sorry im not using Java, i think it exist the same function to copy an object in java

Comment: url is the column name? Shouldnt it be in " " ?

Comment: if you use the Dataset, i think you have a Java class  with id and test attributes, so you can get each attribute without " " like a simple object

Comment: Sorry, but the expression doesnt seem to work in java